# For multiple rows with some identical fields, keep the one with updated values, and mark the others

Tags: sql, sql-server

For multiple rows with identical features, I hope two add few marks/new columns in the original table.

The original table is as below:

```
ID    Start_date    End_Date    Amount
1     2005-01-01    2010-01-01    5
1     2000-07-01    2009-06-01    10
1     2017-08-01    2018-03-01    30
```

I wish to keep one record with the earliest start date, latest end date, added amount and an indicator to tell me to use this record. For the others, just use the indicator to tell me not to use.

The updated table should be as below:

```
ID  Start_date  End_Date    Amount  Amount_new  Usable  Start          End
1   2005-01-01  2010-01-01  5         45         0     2000-07-01     2018-03-01
1   2000-07-01  2009-06-01  10                   1      
1   2017-08-01  2018-03-01  30                   1
```

It does not matter which row to keep, as long as there is one row with Usable=0, and Amount_new, Start and End are updated.

If not considering the end date, I was thinking of grouping by ID and Start_date, then update the column Usable and Amount_new of the first row. However I still have the problem of how to select the first row from the group by group. Considering the End_Date makes my mind even more messy!

Could anyone help to shed some light upon this issue?

Comment: How do you decide which row "to keep" (I.e. Usable = 0)?

Comment: @jarlh Doesn't really matter. For simplicity, could consider there is another column with row number and keep the one with smallest row number. But keep any row would work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
alter table original
    add amount_new int,
    add usable bit,
    add new_start,
    add new_end;
```

Then, you can update it using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select o.*,
             sum(amount) over (partition by id) as x_amount,
             (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by start_date) as x_usable,
             min(start_date) as x_start_date,
             max(end_date) as x_end_date
      from original o
     )
update toupdate
    set new_amount = x_amount,
        usable = x_usable,
        new_start = x_start_date,
        new_end = x_end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT, [Start_date] DATE, End_Date DATE, Amount NUMERIC(28,0), Amount_new NUMERIC(28,0), Usable BIT, Start [Date], [End] [Date])

INSERT INTO #temp (ID, [Start_date], End_Date, Amount) VALUES
(1,'2005-01-01','2010-01-01',5),
(1,'2000-07-01','2009-06-01',10),
(1,'2017-08-01','2018-03-01',30),
(2,'2001-07-01','2009-06-01',5),
(2,'2017-08-01','2019-03-01',35)

UPDATE t1

SET Amount_new = t2.[Amount_new],
    Usable = 1,
    Start = t2.[Start],
    [End] = t2.[End]

FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNO FROM #temp) t1

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ID,[Start_date],[End_Date],[Amount]
    ,SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS [Amount_new]
    ,MIN([Start_date]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS [Start]
    ,MAX(End_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS [End]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNO
FROM #temp ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rno = t1.RNO AND t2.RNO = 1

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

The result is as below,

```
ID  Start_date  End_Date    Amount  Amount_new  Usable  Start       End
1   2005-01-01  2010-01-01  5       45          1       2000-07-01  2018-03-01
1   2000-07-01  2009-06-01  10      NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL
1   2017-08-01  2018-03-01  30      NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL
2   2001-07-01  2009-06-01  5       40          1       2001-07-01  2019-03-01
2   2017-08-01  2019-03-01  35      NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used over partition by before, need to take a deeper look into it :-)